# Get fitted estimator from CV function of XGBoost

Tags: xgboost, cross-validation

Hello stackoverflow community !

I am wondering how can I get the fitted XGBoost trees from the function xgboost.cv() https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html#xgboost.cv.
In sklearn, if we use cross_validate(), we have a parameter `return_estimator = True` that allows to do this https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_validate.html.

Hence my question, is there a way to get use a parameter similar to `return_estimator` in the xboost.cv() function ?

Thank you all ! :)